# Using singleton with proxy pattern together and losing both?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, mfc, callback, singleton

I am passing a callback function to a library. What the callback essentially does is receive updates from the dll and send it to GUI to display. The problem is that since the callback is global or static function, it doesn't know about the GUI and who to pass which in my case will be dialog. The approach I have used to accomplish this is to use singleton and a proxy (sort of).

```
class CDispatcher
{
public:
    CDispatcher(void);
    ~CDispatcher(void);

protected:
    static HWND m_hWnd;

public:
    static void SetWindow( HWND hWnd );
    static void Dispatch(int code, char * msg);
};
```

Later in the code

```
BOOL CTestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // I need to set this before I set callback
    CDispatcher::SetWindow( m_hWnd );

    //now I can set the callback
    LibRegisterCallback( CDispatcher::Dispatch );

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

While this works but first I don't know if my CDispatcher class is good module. It doesn't seem like a good singleton neither it looks like a good proxy. Maybe I could pass the handle of the window in constructor which would make it better but I don't if that's even possible since I am never instantiating the singleton. Another thing is I never how to instantiate CDispatcher because again its just a all global members.

Is this a case where proxy design pattern can be applied in a better way (I am guessing in conjuction with singleton)? Maybe another pattern solves this problem more elegantly? Or is my implementation fine?

Comment: TL;DR; What for heaven's sake is a _'bag of singleton'_? Did you mean factories?

Comment: I meant singleton and proxy but if it was confusing I changed the subject.